# How to calculate 2D soft-body Physics

Tags: mathematical-physics, soft-question, solid-state-physics, elasticity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2d soft body physics mathematics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14785/2d-soft-body-physics-mathematics)

The definition of **rigid body** in Box2d is

> A chunk of matter that is so strong
>   that the distance between any two bits
>   of matter on the chunk is completely
>   constant.

And this is exactly what i don't want as i would like to make ***2D*** (maybe 3D eventually), elastic, deformable, breakable, and even sticky bodies.

What I'm hoping to get out of this community are resources that teach me the math behind how objects bend, break and interact. I don't care about the molecular or chemical properties of these objects, and often this is all I find when I try to search for **how to calculate what a piece of wood, metal, rubber, goo, liquid, organic material, etc. might look like after a force is applied to it.**

Also, I'm a very visual person, so diagrams and such are EXTREMELY HELPFUL for me.